# CMD: Binding result of command to a variable and using it in the next call

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get a simple cmd script to retrieve a secret from Azure Key vault, and set it to my local user secrets setup using `dotnet-secrets`.
This assumes I'm already logged in to the azure cli.

I want to do something like this:

```
set dbConnectionString=az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %dbConnectionString%
```

How can I write this so that it works in a cmd script?

Comment: not farmiliar with azure output on windows, but what output do you get when in `cmd` and running the keyvault command as is? I assume it wil lfail as it is a different cli/shell?

Comment: the output from the first line is a string

Comment: It fails with the message "Unrecognized command or argument 'keyvault'"

Comment: so seems like it will not be able to run from cmdline then.

Comment: I believe it does, running just az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value" prints the secret on the next line

Comment: then surely running this from cmdline will do? `for /f "delims=" %i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"') do set "variable=%i" && echo %variable%`

Comment: Yes.
So now I tried `for /f "delims=" %i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"') do "dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %i"`
 which gives '"dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings "mySecretValue""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: And removing the last "" -> it works! Thanks :D

Comment: If you want to add it as an answer I will accept. The final solution was `for /f "delims=" %i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"') do dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %i`

Comment: Do we have to use a for loop to be able to to this? Seems weird

Comment: Well, the loop in this case does not actually do a loop For each.. as such, as it only runs the command once, with a single output. It is the simplest way to get the result into a variable.

Comment: Ok. So this now works directly in the CMD, but if I put it in a .cmd script and run it, it will complain `DefaultConnection was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: double up on the `%` in the predefined variables ie. `%%i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, use `for` to achieve this:

From cmdline:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"') do set "variable=%i" && echo %variable%
```

from batch-file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "vaultname" --name "name" --query "value"') do set "variable=%%i"
echo %variable%
```